# ASW S3 what permissions are needed to make file downloadable via cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I wonder what EXACT permissions are need to be set for files and foldres to be downloadable via cloud front.

1) I create a S3 Bucket
2) Create cloudfront distribution with origin of created S3 Bucket (there is not questions about it)

3) I create a folder in Bucket "Folder1"
4) I upload files to created Folder

Question:
1) What should I make with "Folder1" and containing files to make them available for download via cloudfront distribution.

My assumtion:
On "Folder1" via menu I should chose "make public" (actually I don't understand fully what is  "Make Public" means, would be grateful if someone explains)
And on EACH file I should add permission: Everyone Open\Download.

Didn't find it in docs (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make public** means that your files are accessible publicly. For doing you have to give **Read permission** to public user.

For more details : [Amazon S3 ACL : Access Control List details](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--access-control-list-details.html)

[Disclosure : [Bucket Explorer]](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know can folders have ACLs?

Comment: There is nothing like folder at S3.. They are just virtual folder... ACL can be set to objects as well as on Bucket.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got that there is only "objects" in the bucket.